# Google signin Issue in Android

Tags: android, authentication

I am trying to signin user with google.

I got the demo code to login, and it is working fine.

Scenario 1: User Login with already existing account.
expected solution: after user selected his/her account, and in onActivityResult i should get the details of the selected email account like, name, pic, email etc etc..... and this is coming correct.

Scenario 2: User can add new account and logged in auatomatically.
Expected solution: When user clicks on signin with google, and selected create new account instead of selecting already existing account. the user will go to the add new account page and insert their credentials, and after successfully adding new account, user should automatically login.

Error : But when user adds new account and comes back to the login page. I am able to get the email, id but givenName, and familyName is null. I need the name of the user.
**Now the account is added in the device, next when user select the newly added account from login page, at that time in onActivityResult i am getting the NAME of the user.**

**What i want is when user adds a new account or select an existing account, it should show me the name of the user**

Here is the code to handleSignIn

LoginActivity.java

```
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> opr = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(mGoogleApiClient);
    if (opr.isDone()) {
        // If the user's cached credentials are valid, the OptionalPendingResult will be "done"
        // and the GoogleSignInResult will be available instantly.
        Log.d(TAG, "Got cached sign-in");
        GoogleSignInResult result = opr.get();
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else {
        // If the user has not previously signed in on this device or the sign-in has expired,
        // this asynchronous branch will attempt to sign in the user silently.  Cross-device
        // single sign-on will occur in this branch.
        opr.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
}


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .build();
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .enableAutoManage(this /* FragmentActivity */, this /* OnConnectionFailedListener */)
            .addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
            .build();
}


 protected void onActivityResult(
        final int requestCode,
        final int resultCode,
        final Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(result);
    } else
        callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}



 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        // Signed in successfully, show authenticated UI.
        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getPhotoUrl " + acct.getPhotoUrl());
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getServerAuthCode " + acct.getServerAuthCode());
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getIdToken " + acct.getIdToken());
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getId " + acct.getId());
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getGivenName " + acct.getGivenName()); //firstName and lastName=""
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getDisplayName " + acct.getDisplayName());
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getEmail " + acct.getEmail());
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getFamilyName " + acct.getFamilyName());
        Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: getAccount " + acct.getAccount());
        Set<Scope> scopeSet = acct.getGrantedScopes();
        for (Scope scope : scopeSet) {
            Log.e(TAG, "handleSignInResult: " + scope.zzpp());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this code

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()
            .requestIdToken("Web client (auto created by Google Service)") // added this line
            .requestProfile()
            .build();
```

Web client is found at https://console.developers.google.com and go to you app.

Select Credentials at left and you will find **Web Client** in **OAuth 2.0 client IDs** section.